# If a column has a default, is a NOT NULL constraint redundant?

Tags: sql

For example...

```
CREATE TABLE phone (
    id            integer primary key,
    country_code  integer not null default 1,
    area_code     integer not null,
    number        integer not null
);
```

Can I safely remove the `not null` from `country_code`?  It's messing with my ORM's validation which thinks `country_code` must be defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The default value is only used for when you don't set the value.

If you remove the `not null` constraint, it will have an initial value, but it could still be manually set to `null`.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how it would be set to null?

Comment: Using an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement that specifies `NULL` for that column.

Comment: @JohnathanWood Silly me, you're right.  I've been so used to auto incrementing primary keys.